# Grep regex doesn't work with Cygwin on Windows

Tags: regex, cygwin, grep

I'm trying to [find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7251363/find-non-ascii-character-existing-tool-or-java-groovy-script) all non ascii chars in a file using grep:

```
grep '[^\x00-\x7F]' myfile
```

I think this should work but it returns each row in the file.

Any ideas?

Comment: ASCII only includes codepoints up to 127 (0x7F).  What happens if you use `[^\x00-\x7F]` instead?

Comment: Oh, yeah! I forgot `grep` doesn't support hexadecimal escapes.  You have to use [POSIX character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html) (e.g. `[^[:ascii]]`).

Answer (score 2):

`grep` doesn't recognize the `\x` syntax.

```
( echo Hello ; echo '\\x48' ) | grep '\x48'
```

prints

```
\x48
```

(`'H'` is character 0x48.)

Your `grep` is matching all lines because each line contains a character other than `\`, `x`, `0`, `7`, `F`, and anything in the range `0` .. `\`.

Note that this is not specific to Cygwin.

GNU grep (which is what Cygwin has) has an experimental `-P` option that tells it to use Perl-like regular expressions; with that option, it does recognize the `\x` syntax.

Comment: I've tried the -P option in cygwin and I can confirm it works.

Answer (score 1):

Grep may be interpreting multibyte (i.e., non-ASCII) characters as several single-byte (ASCII) characters. (This way, this lovely `∩` character [U+2229] would show up as `"` [U+0022] followed by a `)` [U+0029].) You'll need to figure out the file's encoding and use a more-sphisticated system that knows Unicode.

Answer (score 1):

Found that perl works:

perl -n -e  'print if /[^\x00-\x7F]/' file